# Forbid runtime dependency on package in Nix overlay

Tags: package-managers, nix, dependency-resolution

### Task description

I want to make sure that no derivation I install has no run-time dependency on specified set of derivation. If I ask `nix-env` to install package that has such run-time dependency, I want it to say that I am asking for impossible. Build-dependencies are fine. I want to avoid huge cascade rebuilds, though.

In other words, I want to make sure that derivation with `name = evil` never reaches my Nix store, but I am fine that it was used to build other derivations on Hydra. Here is what I tried:

#### Failed attempt: use derivation `meta` attribute

```
self: super: {
  evil = super.evil // { meta.broken = True; };
}
```

but this makes `nix-env` to refuse install programs that has build-time dependencies on `evil`, for example it refuses to install `go` or `haskell` programs (which are statically linked) because compiler has some transitive dependency on `evil`.

### Failed attempt: replace `evil` with something harmless

I write overlay that replaces `evil`:

```
self: super {
  evil = super.harmless; # e.g super.busybox
}
```

it causes major cascade rebuild.

#### Random idea

If there is function, like this:

```
self: super: {
  ghc = forget_about_dependencies_but_retain_hash_yes_I_know_what_I_Do [super.evil] super.ghc;
  # same for rustc, go and other compilers that link statically.
}
```

that would be 90% solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible to prevent some derivation from being in store, but it is possible to make sure profile does not contain run-time dependencies:

```
self: super: {
   world = (super.buildEnv {
     name = "world";
     paths = with super; [ foo bar baz ];
   }).overrideAttrs (_: { disallowedRequisites = [ super.evil super.ugly ]; });
}
```

So, if you put all derivations you want in "world", you can be sure that `evil` and `ugly` are not in dependencies. But they will be downloaded into store to build "world", even if they are not actually used by any derivations in `paths`.